# How to destroy session with browser closing in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Recently I have developed a web application with codeigniter. I am facing a session related problem there badly.

**Problem scenario:**

If user A logged into the application then the user id set in session. After doing task user A closed his browser and leave the computer. A little while later user B came and open browser and see the application was in logged in state. or when user B write down the url and press enter it directly redirected into the application without any authentication by using the previous session.

I used the following configuration for session:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 1800;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

Now my question is how can i destroy all the session with closing browser or browser tab in codeigniter?

Comment: Try setting `$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;`. [`Sessions`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) - Whether to cause the session to expire automatically when the browser window is closed.

Comment: it doesn't work. Is there any other solution?

Comment: Are you storing the sessions in a DB?

Comment: @AlexRichards no i am not storing the sessions in a DB.

Comment: **For future visitors**: First, I tried `$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;` and it didn't work. Then I tried `$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;` and it worked, but this is said to be a [legacy setting](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#session-preferences). So I couldn't really rely on it. Tried the first one again. This time I restarted the Apache, and it worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use javascript and asynchron request.
When you close the window, the handler of window.onunload is called

```
var unloadHandler = function(e){
        //here ajax request to close session
  };
window.unload = unloadHandler;
```

To solve the problem of redirection, php side you can use a counter

```
  class someController  extends Controller {

   public function methodWithRedirection(){

        $this->session->set_userdata('isRedirection', 1);
        //here you can redirect  
   }
}
class homeController extends Controller{
   public function closeConnection(){
        $this->load->library('session');
        if($this->session->userdata('isRedirection')!== 1){
            //destroy session
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: yes it is a solution but one problem there with page redirecting the session cleared then the application disappeared.

Comment: So use a counter php side. And when the counter is 0 then you do destroy the session.

Answer (score 8):

Edit the `config.php` file and set `sess_expire_on_close` to `true`.

e.g

```
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 4):

Add a logout button.

Have that button destroy the session with CI's [built in destroy function](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html?highlight=session%20destroy#CI_Session::sess_destroy).

```
$this->session->sess_destroy();
```

Comment: this is the most sane approach. yet the framework kids want everything done automatically. that's why frameworks should not be used by newbies.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this, and see if this helps.

https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/PK-Session

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't know if you already had the solution, but I found myself in the same scenario in CodeIgniter version 3.0. In `config.php`, go to `Session Variables` section and you can set:

```
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
```

> [**sess_expiration**](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#session-preferences): The number of seconds you would like the session to last. If you would like a non-expiring session (until browser is closed) set the value to zero: 0

Comment: I get that, but what if you want your session to expire on different scenarios? For example, expire the session in one hour or when the browser closes. How do you handle that?

Comment: The first time I used this, it didn't work. I had to restart Apache, and then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

in **$config.php** file

```
change  $config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
```

**to**

```
$config['sess_expiration'] = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply set `sess_expiration =0` in `application/config/config.php` file
as stated in Codeigniter [documentation](http://localhost/yogapanel/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#session-preferences)

Answer (score 0):

Open the general config file **application/config/config.php**, search for $config[‘**sess_expiration**’]

change

```
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
```

to

```
$config['sess_expiration'] = -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

for CI-3.0.4 locate the items below inside "config.php" and set accordingly

```
$config['sess_expiration'] = -1;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this way. Can this help you?

Change

```
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
```

The result of above code is :

[image]

To

```
$config['sess_expiration'] = time() + 7200;
```

And the result of changed line is :

[image]

Now, if you close the browser window, the session will be deleted automatically.