# How to destroy session with browser closing in codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, destroy

First of all I should remind you I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174297/how-to-destroy-session-with-browser-closing-in-codeigniter) , I am using **Codeigniter 3** .
I want  to destroy session with browser closing like PHP session !
I have read somethings about using ajax like this :

```
var unloadHandler = function(e){
        //here ajax request to close session
  };
window.unload = unloadHandler;
```

and .... 
But I dont want to  make myself dependent to js for destroy session with browser closing .
this is my `config.php`

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'soheil_blog_name';

$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174297/how-to-destroy-session-with-browser-closing-in-codeigniter

Comment: this is not about Codeigniter 3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just have to set 'sess_expiration' to 0, as described in the [manual](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html#session-preferences) and in the [config.php comments](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/3.0.2/application/config/config.php#L329).

*Note: Technically, you can't really destroy the session when the browser is closed. You can only tell the browser to discard the session cookie after it is closed, but the session itself is still usable on the server-side (i.e. if you are the victim of a MITM attack and somebody stole the session ID).

The session is actually deleted later by the garbage collector.*

Comment: Keep in mind that even with `sess_expiration` set to 0, if the user is using the browser setting of 'Continue where you left off', the browser won't even remove the cookie.  So, it isn't that Codeigniter is doing something wrong, it is just in certain scenarios, the browser itself can cause this feature not to work as expected.  This is discussed further in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617954/chrome-doesnt-delete-session-cookies